# Create backdrop for open modal - CSS NO BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to find the simplest solution to this problem. I just want the background of my open modal to have a grey out look to it. I can't seem to find any straight forward answer to this problem. I'm close to accomplishing this though. Right now my javascript adds a class to the entire body of the app when the modal is open. The class is called `openModal`. My current attempt is to call `opacity: 0.4;` on that class. This does add an opacity to the page. but it also covers the modal. which I don't want to happen. How can I have the modal overwrite the opacity?

Here is my CSS.

```
.openModal {
  opacity: 0.3;

  .proceeds-modal {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 95%;
    right: 2%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: $base-background-color;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0.2px 0.6px 0.5px 0.5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what the problem is without any HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, I would recommend setting an `rgba()` background on `.openModal`, like `.openModal { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }`

Or you could always use a pseudo element of `.openModal` instead, and use `rgba()` or use `opacity` like you already tried.

```css
.proceeds-modal {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 95%;
  right: 2%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0.2px 0.6px 0.5px 0.5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.openModal:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="openModal">
  <div class="proceeds-modal">
    modal
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the following basic HTML structure:

```
<div class="main-container">
  This is the page main content
</div>

<div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay"></div>

<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-container-controls">
        <button class="modal-container-close-button">Close modal button</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-container-content">
        <p><strong>Modal title</strong></p>
        <p>Modal content text 1</p>
        <p>Modal content text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 different `div`s:

- `modal-overlay` is used for the *background layer* between the main body and your modal
- `modal-container` is used for the modal itself

This way, you can style them differently.

You can read more about developing a custom modal [here](https://rapaccinim.medium.com/how-to-create-a-custom-resizable-modal-with-scrollable-and-fixed-content-21adb2adda28).